# How to setup dev environment on a single host, simulating two disctinct servers

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

My pet project includes two servers. Each has its own docker-compose environment, with nginx at the front end, and different images/services behind.

These servers are on the same domain, say at main.example.com and subdomain.example.com.

The goal is to run both instances on my dev machine, to ease debug, testing etc...

I understand that the same port (namely 80/443 here) can be assigned only once within a host, so my two servers (or more!) cannot easily be present at the same time.

But is there a way of getting close to this? One constraint I have is I'd like to work with real domain names as much as possible, avoiding hard-coding IPs etc... Knowing that one exercise I have in mind is implementing a DNS server in the main.example.com server for the subdomain ones. So sticking to a setup as close to reality as possible it important.

I have thought of running docker in docker, to wrap all this into another layer of networking, simulating going through a WAN, but apparently this is quite a can of worms, and I am not event sure this would give me what I want at the networking level.

Is there a solution to this? Or am I way better off using at least two physical hosts (meaning not being easily able to work on the move etc...)?

Thanks!

Comment: You could run this on two (Linux) VMs on your local system, and then run Docker and the rest of the stack on each of the VMs.  Topologically that'd be very similar to what you're deploying on to.  I wouldn't try to do live development in that environment, but it'd be very useful for testing deployment setups and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with an advice: **Don't use real production hostnames in your dev environment.** All environment dependent configuration should be provided to your application by environment variables. Your application should therefore access the host which is defined in e.g. $OTHER_HOST, no matter if it's an IP address or a hostname.

Back to your question. You can easily use Docker compose to spin up your dev environment with two different containers. A simple example can look like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  microservice:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=demo
      - DB_USER=demo
      - DB_PASS=demo

  database:
    image: "postgres:alpine"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=demo
      - POSTGRES_USER=demo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=demo
```

This example uses the Dockerfile to build the image called "microservice" and sets environment variables for the database. A second image for the database just gets pulled from Dockerhub and configured by environment variables.